# Time difference in correct format oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to difference between two time.

```
select 
    extract(hour from intrvl) as hh24,
    extract(minute from intrvl) as mi
from 
    (select   
         to_timestamp_tz ('23:45','hh24:mi')
           - to_timestamp_tz ('08:00','hh24:mi') as intrvl
     from dual);

output-hh24-15
       mi-45
```

Desired output:

```
hh24-08
mi-15
```

Comment: not sure I understand what you want.  how do you get minutes = 15?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - it is showing the difference from 8 Am to 23:45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this

```sql
SELECT MOD (TRUNC (intrvl), 24) AS hours, (intrvl - TRUNC (intrvl)) * 60 AS minutes
  FROM (SELECT 24 - ((TO_DATE ('23:45', 'hh24:mi') - TO_DATE ('08:00', 'hh24:mi')) * 24)    AS intrvl
          FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: I am using query which is shared by you but when i am changing the value it is not behaving properly-----SELECT TRUNC (intrvl) AS hours, 
(intrvl - TRUNC (intrvl)) * 60 AS minutes
  FROM (SELECT 24 - ((TO_DATE ('07:30', 'hh24:mi') - TO_DATE ('08:00', 'hh24:mi')) * 24)    AS intrvl
          FROM DUAL);    output-24 hours 30 minutes

Comment: Just updated the query to use MOD when calculating the hours. Please give it a try now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the part fo the day outside your time range - which is the only way I can see you'd get 08:15 - you can subtract your interval result from an interval of one day:

```
select 
    extract(hour from intrvl) as hh24,
    extract(minute from intrvl) as mi
from (
    select interval '1' day
             - (to_timestamp_tz ('23:45','hh24:mi')
                 - to_timestamp_tz ('08:00','hh24:mi')) as intrvl
    from dual
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=36c9cace2c8c8510c7cd33c80966e87f)